# RTK query Opimistic or Pessimistic update not working when GET method has pagination

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Here I'm trying to create a new brand by optimistic updating the new brand post, but due to query param of 'GET' method which is page actually I think the whole process is not working. I checked by giving 1,2,3 in here [brandCategoryApi.util.updateQueryData('brand', 1, (draftsPost) =>] it only get access to that but update in the UI still did not happened somehow!
So how can I access the page parameter in other query/mutation methods kinldy give me a way. Thank you.

```
    brand: builder.query({
       query: (page) => ({
        url: `/admin/brand/list/`,
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          page,
        },
      }),

      providesTags: (result) => result
          ? result!.results?.map((value) => ({ type: 'brands', id: value?.id }))
          : [{ type: 'brands', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),

    createBrand: builder.mutation<any, any>({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: '/admin/brand/create/',
        method: 'POST',
        body,
      }),

      // optimistic update on creating brand
      async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        console.log('Arguments on creating brand', args);

        dispatch(
          brandCategoryApi.util.updateQueryData('brand', args, (draftsPost) => {
            console.log('draft results', draftsPost);
            draftsPost.results.push(args);
            return draftsPost;
          })
        );

        try {
          await queryFulfilled;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
       },
    }),
```

`

`

I'm expecting to get a solve like how to access according to page param or some other way to solve this when I'm having a pagination in the query method.